# Leak when running PyObjC template in XCode 4

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, pyobjc

I downloaded the only Xcode PyObjC template I could find from: http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-xcode/ (the 'Cocoa-Python Core Data Document-based Application/'). When I ran it - without modifying, I get a leak where the "responsible library" is: **_objc.so**

How can I resolve this? Can I define an auto pool in python to take care of this?

Comment: What's the leaked object? Is it `NSPlaceholderString`?

Comment: how do I find which object in Instruments? Here is what I see: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22358199/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-08%20at%201.31.48%20PM.png

Answer (score 1):

Check out these more up to date templates... https://github.com/gregneagle/Xcode4CocoaPythonTemplates

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded them. I tried Profile > Leaks on the simplest Cocoa-Python template, and it leaks in the same spot. Do you get the leak too or is it just me?

Comment: ps. am I obsession about something too minor?